# Swift TableViewController is in Landscape

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, url, orientation

I have a tableViewController that when a row is tapped on goes to a url using a KINWebBrowserViewController. The tableViewController should only be in portrait but the KINWebBrowserViewController can be landscape or portrait. When I go back to the tableViewController in landscape the tableViewController is also in landscape. How can I stop this?

The code for orientation:

```
class CustomNC: UINavigationController {

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        if visibleViewController is KINWebBrowserViewController { return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue) }
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)}
}
```

The code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let linkItem = linkLabels[indexPath.row] as String

    let webBrowser = KINWebBrowserViewController()
    let url = NSURL(string: linkItem)
    webBrowser.actionButtonHidden = true
    webBrowser.loadURL(url)

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webBrowser, animated: true)
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Put a print() statement in your custom supportedInterfaceOrientations() method. When is the method called? What value is it returning? If you rotate the phone after the table has fully reappeared, does it print something every rotation?

Comment: Can you force the orientation for the tableviewcontroller to portrait, Would this be of any help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8

Comment: The method is called when ever the view rotates. Every rotation works but as said when returning in landscape the table is in landscape.

Comment: Everything is working because I forced the tableview to go to portrait but I get this message: Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

Comment: That is likely to be a completely separate problem, perhaps the timing of how you handle the segues. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425775/what-to-do-about-finishing-up-a-navigation-transition-in-an-unexpected-state-n or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518856/uinavigationcontroller-corrupted-navigation-bar-issue